# unwanted divs created with dom php

Tags: php, dom

Can create primary div without xml tags displaying and without any problem

```
$myfile = fopen("../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$ele = $dom->createElement('div', $textcon);
$ele ->setAttribute('id', $divname);
$ele ->setAttribute('style', 'background: '.$divbgcolor.'; color :'.$divfontcolor.' ;display : table-col; width :100%;');
$dom->appendChild($ele);
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
fwrite($myfile,$html);
fclose($myfile);
```

Trying to create child div but the below code creates duplicates of parent div and child div and adds XML tags after every div

```
$myfile = fopen("../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
$file = "../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
$ele = $doc->createElement('div', $textcon);
$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$element->appendChild($ele);
$ele ->setAttribute('id', $divname);
$ele ->setAttribute('style', 'background: '.$divbgcolor.'; color :'.$divfontcolor.' ;display : table-cell;');
$doc->appendChild($ele);
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
fwrite($myfile,$html);
```

Comment: Please show us your resulting html to get help

Comment: So are you good on this with the solution I provided or do you still need help bro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update

How about this

You will have three files,  $outputfile will be a new file to save the html to.  the $parentfile and $childfile are the two files you want to pull divs out of .  $pId is the ID of the parent div,  $cId is the ID of the child div  (which should have been set when the files were created if im not mistaken)

```
$outputfile = '/path/to/new/output/file/';
$parentfile = '/path/to/file/with/parent/div/';
$childfile = '/path/to/file/with/child/div/';
$pId = 'myParentDivId';
$cId = 'myChildDivId';

$file = $parentfile;

$p = new DOMDocument();
$p->loadHTMLFile($file);
$pEle = $p->getElementById($pId);

$file = $childfile;

$c = new DOMDocument();
$c->loadHTMLFile($file);
$cEle = $c->getElementById($cId);

$pEle->appendChild($cEle);

$m = new DOMDocument();

$m->appendChild($pEle);

$myfile = fopen($outputfile, "a+") or die('bye');
$html = $m->saveHTML();
fwrite($myfile,$html);
fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: i am creating the parent div from a nother file and the child fiv from a nother file, how will i select the parent div to insert the child dive when i creating the child div from a nother file, srry if i am askin a stupid question, have spent a lot of time tryint to reosolve this, feeling kinda dizzy! :)

Comment: You should upvote my answer so i have enough rep to comment.  :)     Let me see what I can figure out.   So you basically want to take the file we made before, and import it into a new object and then put a child div inside the existing div right?

Comment: just click the up arrow above the 0 to the left of my answer.   and if my answer is right, of course, click the checkmark too.  :)    You might not have enough rep to upvote yet.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, did you try the updated code I put in my answer above?

Comment: i have reached home now, tom i'll check in the office and update the status, thank you so much

Comment: can you tell me brother, where can i learn more about php dom in detail ?

Comment: I just used the table of contents on this page ...http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I never even actually used domdocument before today haha.

Comment: ah man, that's cool, your iq level is awesome then :) am lucky i met you, keep goin bro

Comment: thanks bro,   yeah i think its more my 10+ years of programming every day,  that helps to figure stuff like this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Change a+  to w+, Also change saveXML to saveHTML

It will solve the issues

Thanks

Comment: w+ will rewrite the file, a+ is what i want to add data to the file, i have changed xml to html. The remaining code is the same. i am creating the parent div from a different file and child div from another file, both into the same file

Comment: Are you sure duplicate divs are not due to appending of same html to same file?and also saveHTML didn't help to remove xml tags?please let me know

Comment: i have edited the code to what i have now above, please have a look, it creates multiple divs when creating child div and adds xml tags after every child div

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template to create a parent and append child nodes at will.

```
<?php
    $oDom                     = new DOMDocument( '1.0', 'UTF-8' );
    $oDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $oDom->formatOutput       = true;
    $iErrorFlag               = true;
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    $oLog = $oDom->createElement( 'log' );
    $oDom->appendChild( $oLog );
    $oNde = $oDom->createElement( 'lognode' );
    $oLog->appendChild( $oNde );

    $oNde->appendChild( $oDom->createElement( 'message', 'My message!' ) );
    $oNde->appendChild( $oDom->createElement( 'user'   , 'My user!'    ) );
    $oNde->appendChild( $oDom->createElement( 'ip'     , 'My ip!'      ) );

    $bSuccess = file_put_contents( 'logfile.xml', $oDom->saveXML() );
?>
```

Comment: if i create a parent div in one instance, then i want to create a child div in a nother instance, what should i do, please help

Comment: You can replicate the object twice and do append/customize as needed on each object. They'll be unique from one another. I generally use that approach. e.g. $oDom2 = new DOMDocument...

Comment: i am creating the parent div from a nother file and the child fiv from a nother file, how will i select the parent div to insert the child dive when i creating the child div from a nother file, srry if i am askin a stupid question, have spent a lot of time tryint to reosolve this, feeling kinda dizzy! :)

Comment: Ooo...! Should be just fine. Append this inside a function and pass the $oDom object with that div from one file to the other.